# Smallest and Second Smallest of a number list

Tags: java

Problem 2
Write your program in the file TwoSmall.java.

Input a set of positive integers, ending with -1 as a sentinel. Print the smallest and second smallest of these numbers in that order.

You may assume there are always at least two numbers before the -1; you do NOT have to check for this being true.

```
public class TwoSmall{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int min;
        int secondMin;
        int sentinel = -1;

        System.out.println("Enter atleast two numbers");    
        int input = IO.readInt();

        min = input;
        secondMin = input;

        do{

                if(input < min){
                    secondMin = min; 
                    min = input;
                }

                else if (input < secondMin) {
                    secondMin = input; 
                }
                input = IO.readInt();
            } while(input!=sentinel);

            System.out.println(min);
            System.out.println(secondMin);
    }

}
```

This is not working? Could someone tell me what is wrong with this program?

Comment: Have you tried going through it step-by-step, either by thinking through it in your head, using print statements throughout program flow to track it, or using an actual debugger?

Comment: IO.readInt only reads 1 int at a time, but right now you are setting min and secondMin to input after reading.  Shouldn't you have two IO.readInt calls for each of these variables?

Comment: Can you say more about how it's failing?

Comment: "This is not working" please describe what you fed in, and what was the output

Answer (score 2):

It's because you set both `min` and `secondMin` equal to the first entered value. Unless the numbers entered are less than that value, you'll have an issue. Try reading in both those numbers separately.

```
min = IO.readInt();
secondMin = IO.readInt();
```

Also, rethink your logic. You might be getting a backwards result. A way to work yourself around this problem is to read the first two integers, then assign them to `min` and `secondMin` accordingly. Otherwise, if the user enters 4,3,2 -- the result will say that 3 is the lowest and that 2 is the second lowest - which is incorrect.

Another option, as mentioned by @vandale is to initialize both of them to `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE`. If you do this, you eliminate the need to read in initial values for `min` and `secondMin`.

Comment: Another option is to Initialize them to `Integer,MAX_VALUE`